# Is there a way to check server's session timeout without having access to the server itself?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6, session-timeout

Basically I am interacting with a `.NET` web application and I want to know what is the session timeout of that server.

I know that usually for `IIS 6` is between 8-20 minutes by default but I want the specific timeout without speculating or keeping timers etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the browser you want to know the session time out?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I'd use a timer with a conservative value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I was thinking of somehow sending a specific request to the server and the server would reply with this variable. However, timer is the only way I guess.

Comment: Also I am not sure that the timeout is hard and fast. I think timeouts are often treated as a time after which you are allowed to ditch it. Usually it won't be far off but it depends what precision you want the answer to be. I know this mainly from doing some experiments with timeouts set to 5 seconds to test some stuff. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think is possible unless the server explicitly has provisions to allow it (expose it) to the front-end querying the server's services...

Comment: what do you guys think?